# Refer to a schema inside a class

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, schema

Users in my database are declared inside a class as follows:

```
class User {
    constructor() {
        this.user = mongoose.model('user', {
            email: String,
            name: String,
        })
    }
    validPassword(collection, password) {
        ... ...
    }
}

const user  = new User();
module.exports = user;
```

In my `PostSchema`, I want `author` to point to the above Schema, but I don't know how to write the part after `ref:`. I tried `User`, it gave me an error `MongooseError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "User".`

```
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, default: "DefaultTitle" },
    author: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
})
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: do you import User before Posts ?

Comment: Yes, I do... @JulienTASSIN

Comment: Can you try with 'user' (downcase) in your ref ?

Comment: @JulienTASSIN it works! could you tell what this `user` refer to? There are too many `user` in my code...

Comment: good news ! I post the explanation as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn your ref to 'user' with a downcase.
This notation refers to mongodb [dbref](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#dbrefs)

The ref is the collection name wich is in your case (according to the schema declaration) "user" in downcase.

This will be your Post declaration :

```
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, default: "DefaultTitle" },
    author: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' },
})
```